# ELV to 5amp circuit?

Tags: lighting, cord-and-plug

I have a load of extra low voltage IKEA lamps, each with its own chunky plug-transformer.

[image: ELV transformer plug]

I recently moved to a house with a 5amp lighting circuit with the small round-pin plug sockets, controlled by a light switch.

[image: 5a round pin socket]

I don't really want to replace every 5a plug socket with 15a square pin variants (not least because I don't want to accidentally plug anything into them other than lamps).

Is there any way to adapt the ELV lamps to use the 5amp sockets?

Comment: You should not use receptacles for voltages other than their standard.

Comment: @DanD. I'm not - they're all UK 240v. The ELV lamps have a transformer built into the UK 3 square pin plug (with either 3a or 5a fuses), but I want to use them with 5a round pin sockets.

Comment: I couldn't tell from the question. Your response makes me think what you want is a _plug adapter_. The question then becomes which one.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly.  Your best approach is to consult with IKEA about powering the lights from one single common low-voltage transformer/supply.

Nobody, not even Ikea, thinks a bunch of chunky transformers is the way to go. They did it that way because that is the lowest-cost way to sell the lamps in a single unit and still get the items listed by your regulatory agencies.   They may even have an Ikea-approved way to use a common transformer.

Generally, low voltage power is much more lightly regulated, so the low-voltage cable run from wall-wart to lamp proper is thus less regulated.   That's still a good idea, but with one common transformer if possible.  If that transformer has a cord, feel free to put a 5A receptacle and <=5A fuse.

Comment: Any idea how to consult with IKEA? I asked in store and they didn't have a clue what I was asking about.

Comment: Weird.  They sell low voltage lighting as components; power supply, puck lights, strip lights, connecting cables, etc. The people who support that system ought to understand what you're asking.   Can you post photos of the power brick and if possible, light in question? What bulbs does it take?

Comment: question updated with photos.

Comment: You may not like this response, but ... That transformer looks like it's for halogen/incandescents.    It will be a net financial savings to pay for  LED fixtures that will use ~4 watts instead of ~25 watts.  And you can run them all off 1-2 power supplies and remove the power block issue entirely.    Rule of thumb, if you pay 12 pence/cents a kwh for power, the annual cost of  a wasted watt is 1 quid/dollar.  Factor down for loads not on 24x7.

Comment: the lamps are halogens - free standing chrome ones that were about £120 each when new. I don't really want to replace them, though all my other lights are now LED.

Comment: You're right at those prices, find a way to keep the fixtures.  Which halogen replacement bulb do you use?